# IMG going to new line (Alignment issues)

Tags: html, css

I have a copyright footer which has text and a small logo; the problem is that on a screen ( with a small size as a mobile ) it looks ok, but on a mobile, the IMG goes to a new line (underneath the text not over it).

```
  <div class="copyrightbar">
  <div id="copyright">Copyright &#169; 2014 <img style="padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 5px;" src="images/copyright.png" width="65" height="19" alt=""/> </div>
</div>  

.copyrightbar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: 600;
}
#copyright{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Globerb;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #646566;
    top: 8px;
    z-index:4999;   
}
#copyright img {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -2px;
}
```

I'm new to css, so sorry if I'm not professional.

Comment: Please create a demo in Fiddle.net

Comment: If you have got an online link to show, share the link.

Comment: The code posted always places the image below the text, since it positions them “absolutely”. Please post code that actually reproduces the problem. And at least for debugging, use color contrast (between text and background) that makes the text reasonably readable.

Comment: So how come it doesn't show below it on a normal PC but only on Mob Jukka?

Comment: I did test on a normal PC. As it stands, this is a non-question with an accepted non-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may exists because the image size exceeds the size of the mobile screen, so there was a drop line because the image has no place. Try to reduce the image with `width` & `hight`.

You can even try to remove the `position:absolute;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the logo image responsive that way it will shrink down when the screen size is to small instead of getting bumped down. Try setting the height and having the width set to auto.

```
  <div class="copyrightbar">
  <div id="copyright">Copyright &#169; 2014 <img style="padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 5px;" src="images/copyright.png" width="auto" height="19" alt=""/> </div>
```

Comment: It fits in the page size, the issue is that its not going in line with the text :s

Comment: If you put the image tag before the text what happens? @belthazorNv

Comment: I think it is just getting bumped down because you have hard coded in how large the image must be. @belthazorNv